# How to add an enter to make each line from excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have the code here and It won't let me add enter space from the cell.

```
="YEAR-TO-DATE SALES REPORT "
&"Should be at "&TEXT(NETWORKDAYS("12/31/2017",TODAY()-1)/370*(100),"0.00") &"% to goal if months are weighted evenly "
&"as of end of day "  &TEXT(TODAY()-1,"ddddddddd mm.dd.yyyy")
```

I would like to be three different line.

```
YEAR-TO-DATE SALES REPORT    
Should be at xx.xx% to goal if months are weighted evenly    
As of end of day Tuesday 03.20.2018
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `& CHAR(10) &` And make sure you have wrap text set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CHAR(10):

```
="YEAR-TO-DATE SALES REPORT "
&CHAR(10)&"Should be at "&TEXT(NETWORKDAYS("12/31/2017",TODAY()-1)/370*(100),"0.00") &"% to goal if months are weighted evenly "
&CHAR(10)&"as of end of day "  &TEXT(TODAY()-1,"ddddddddd mm.dd.yyyy")
```

Make sure You have chosen Wrap Text:

[image]

Comment: Well the only difference between your formula and mine is the addition of `CHAR(10)`  which is the line break.  It is an actual character with an actual code.